# Is possible access in a specific control using the value of a variable?

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a function that by the variable "number" goes to specify the number of the control that I've to change color.

```
Private Function match_color(partita, number)
    If partita = "W" Then
        MetroTile1.BackColor = Color.Green 'this is a specific control
    ElseIf partita = "D" Then

    ElseIf partita = "L" Then

    End If
End Function
```

My goal is for example to access the control number 2, so I call the `match_color` function:

```
match_color("D",2)
```

and the number of control to change color is `MetroTile2.BackColor = Color...`
I don't know if I have made clear the idea, but simply is the variable **"number"** that specifies the number of the control to which change color.

Comment: Note that VB.NET is a strongly typed language, so don't make weakly typed by omitting the type in the method signature. Otherwise everything is `Object`, that's not what was originally intended. Start with changing `Option String Off` to `On`.

Comment: I know in reality the number of control, this corresponds to some factors that are given to variables. To avoid the redundant code for every Metrotile, I was wondering if it was indeed possible to access the specific control by changing only the variable "number"

Comment: @tim-schmelter did you mean **Option Strict** ?

Comment: @Rubidium37: of course :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your business logic depend on the number that a control has in it's parent control? That's pointless and error-prone. Having said that, you could use `Controls.Find`:

```
Dim controls = Me.Controls.Find("MetroTile" & number, True) ' False if not recursive
If controls.Length > 0 Then
    controls(0).BackColor = Color.Green ' or use a loop if you expect multiple
End If
```